# Nodes timing out in umbraco back-end

Tags: timeout, umbraco

I'm having an issue with an umbraco site of mine: For some reason some of the nodes are timing out when I try to click on them in the back-end of the site.

The front-end works fine and there aren't any slowdown issues there, however I'm unable to edit these same nodes in the back-end as the system seems to just hang. This is making it incredibly difficult to debug as I have no idea what properties are actually causing the problems here. What's strange is I can create a node of the same document type and enter in some dummy values and that works fine, yet I can't seem to edit the existing nodes.

I've tried republishing the entire site, republishing the individual nodes, deleting the umbraco.config file and nothing has worked up to this point.

What's also interesting is that if I close down the browser the system seems to stop hanging and I can log in and try again.

Has anyone encountered this before or know where to begin?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using? What browser are you using?

Comment: umbraco 4.7 and chrome. Although the same thing seemed to happen in ie..

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Nope, I still have no idea what's wrong

Comment: Did you check the logs, and data types like I suggest in my answer?

Comment: Righto, it turns out it was because of a macro that I was using - when I turned off 'Render content in editor' for the offending macro, it instantly returned back to normal. Although your answer didn't detail the specific problem, it certainly led me in the right direction and I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered something similar. The longer you work with Umbraco the slower it becomes and if you check the memory usage in Chrome's task manager, you can see that certain actions upon nodes bump the memory usage up a little further. The answer is just to close down the tab and open a new one.

I have reported this and Umbraco cannot replicate this. However, I *do* think that this is possibly due to maybe a package installed into Umbraco, maybe uComponents. It's very difficult to pin point.

**Update:**

If you can access some nodes but not others, then this is actually slightly easier to debug. I would check what similarities the nodes that timeout have.

- Are they all of the same document type?
- Do they all use the same data type?

I would guess that the nodes in question are using a data type that is performing an operation when the node is loading, and that operation is timing out. For example, do you have any data types that load data from the database, like enums? Do you have any datatypes that load data from a web service?

Do you have any usercontrol data types wrapped in the UserControlWrapper data type? These would be somewhere to check.

Finally, check:

- The databases [umbracoLog] table. Any Umbraco-specific errors will be listed there.
- Check the computer's event viewer. This will show any unhandled errors.

My money's on a database timeout.

Comment: The problem is that I can't even access certain nodes. The rest of the nodes work incredibly fast but other ones cause the system to hang. No idea what's causing it either and it's incredibly difficult to debug something you can't even access!